# Concat an item with a loop variable in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a set of item that has the same name so I add at the end of each the position number like :P77_VARIABLE_1, :P77_VARIABLE_2.

So in the process to add them to my database I must get those item and make a loop. The loop will look like this

```
for i in 1..:P77_NOMBRE_VARIABLE
  loop
    l_variable := new SFD_SI_VARIABLE_TYP(sfd_si_variable_seq.nextval, :P77_NOM_VARIABLE_i, :P77_TYPE_VARIABLE_i);
    SFD_SI_VARIABLE_PKG.AJOUTER(l_variable);
  end loop;
```

But the problem is this doesn't work. Can someone know a way to execute this loop and adding "dynamically" my item (or a better way for the concatenation with the variable **i**. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving off whether this is a wise thing to do (using individual variables for what should probably be an array, e.g. using an Apex collection), you can use the `v()` function for this.

```
for i in 1..:P77_NOMBRE_VARIABLE
loop
  l_variable := new SFD_SI_VARIABLE_TYP(sfd_si_variable_seq.nextval
    ,v('P77_NOM_VARIABLE_'||i)
    ,v('P77_TYPE_VARIABLE_'||i));
  SFD_SI_VARIABLE_PKG.AJOUTER(l_variable);
end loop;
```